# Capturing stdout from script and storing in java string

Tags: java, io

There have been many questions asked about capturing stdout and storing it into a string, but most of that stdout has been something either produced by a user or outputted by a direct java function. In my case, from my java program, I am launching a script that prints a series of file paths to stdout. It is a script that uses `find` command to return file paths. I want to capture these file paths and store them into a string in my Java code that I can later use within another function of the java program.

My Code:

```
launchOnCommandLine("./getFilepaths.sh");
```

This will spit out a series of file paths to the console window, and I want to capture these and store it into a string.

There are a lot of examples regarding `ByteArrayOutputStream` but I don't quite understand how I can use it in my context.

Comment: Can you perhaps pipe them in a file and use that as input?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream() ?

I think you can do something like:

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("process.sh");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
p.waitFor();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    /* Do whatever you need we the current line */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Process.getInputStream()` can handle it, but it has some caveats that can lead to deadlocks if you're not careful about reading from your streams: [Some reading here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Suggested, safer alternative if you're using Java 1.7 is to use the `ProcessBuilder` class instead: [Some more reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).